# Keycloak Mail Templates: force `Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable` for text MIME part

Tags: email, keycloak, mime

I'm using Keycloak 15.0.2. When sending an account verification email, the email that gets sent uses `Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit` for the text portion of the email.

This causes the verification link to be on one line, and violates [RFC 2822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#section-2.1.1) by having a line that's very long, causing my emails to be bounced.

The HTML portion of the email is properly encoded with `Content-Transfer-Encoding:  quoted-printable`.

I've been trying to look at the source of Keycloak, but my knowledge of java is too poor to really figure it out. I'm sure somewhere the MIME message gets parsed at which point it decides on a header for each part. But I can't find where.

I have seen messages where the text portion *did* have the correct encoding. So I assume there's a certain condition somewhere that will force the encoding. But I can't find it.

How can I force Keycloak (or Freemarker, or javax `MimeBodyPart`) to use `quoted-printable`?

Example of a MIME output:

```
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;    boundary="----=_Part_2_1488711957.1660016366185"
Date: Tue, 9 Aug 2022 03:39:26 +0000 (GMT)
From: Mails@covle.com
MIME-Version: 1.0
Message-ID: <126146379.3.1660016366188@b02efe4baa19>
Received: from b02efe4baa19 by mailhog.example (MailHog)
          id duuNy3ONelpvr8ukUqz7WBJnrtPd0oSw43G2W9w8Ix4=@mailhog.example; Tue, 09 Aug 2022 03:39:26 +0000
Reply-To: Mails@example.com
Return-Path: <Mails@examplecom>
Subject: Verify email
To: asdasd@example.com

------=_Part_2_1488711957.1660016366185
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

Someone has created a Bluppie account with this email address. If this was you, click the link below to verify your email address

http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/bluppie/login-actions/action-token?key=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCIgOiAiSldUIiwia2lkIiA6ICIzODYxY2JmMy0wMWYzLTRhMmQtOTg1NC02MmEyYWMyYzhjNzUifQ.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.yrTUf2tl521Q00IUL-2dWTnugUt_ZeATa3W3IrgoRGM&client_id=account&tab_id=Q_Cn8JV4XYA
[NOTE: The line above is the RFC violation.]

This link will expire within 5 minutes.

If you didn't create this account, just ignore this message.
------=_Part_2_1488711957.1660016366185
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

<html>
<body>
<p>Someone has created a Bluppie account with this email address. If this w=
as you, click the link below to verify your email address</p><p><a href=3D"=
http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/bluppie/login-actions/action-token?key=3D=
eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCIgOiAiSldUIiwia2lkIiA6ICIzODYxY2JmMy0wMWYzLTRhMmQ=
tOTg1NC02MmEyYWMyYzhjNzUifQ.eyJleHAiOjE2NjAwMTY2NjYsImlhdCI6MTY2MDAxNjM2Niw=
ianRpIjoiZDVlYjlhODMtMDE0NS00YTBhLTk2M2YtYjBkMjI0ZTA0ZWVkIiwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cD=
ovL2xvY2FsaG9zdDo4MDgwL2F1dGgvcmVhbG1zL2JsdXBwaWUiLCJhdWQiOiJodHRwOi8vbG9jY=
Wxob3N0OjgwODAvYXV0aC9yZWFsbXMvYmx1cHBpZSIsInN1YiI6IjIxOGQ1NzkzLTA0NmYtNDQ4=
NS04ZmIxLTQ0M2E5NjEyM2FmZiIsInR5cCI6InZlcmlmeS1lbWFpbCIsImF6cCI6ImFjY291bnQ=
iLCJub25jZSI6ImQ1ZWI5YTgzLTAxNDUtNGEwYS05NjNmLWIwZDIyNGUwNGVlZCIsImVtbCI6Im=
FzZGFzZEBjb3ZsZS5jb20iLCJhc2lkIjoiNmM3ZTk5NGItZTA0ZS00ZTlkLWFkNTQtZjE1MGM4N=
jcwYzdmLlFfQ244SlY0WFlBLmQ1MzI3MTMwLWIzY2EtNDY4Ny1iZDZkLWViZWFiODAwZTdkMyIs=
ImFzaWQiOiI2YzdlOTk0Yi1lMDRlLTRlOWQtYWQ1NC1mMTUwYzg2NzBjN2YuUV9DbjhKVjRYWUE=
uZDUzMjcxMzAtYjNjYS00Njg3LWJkNmQtZWJlYWI4MDBlN2QzIn0.yrTUf2tl521Q00IUL-2dWT=
nugUt_ZeATa3W3IrgoRGM&client_id=3Daccount&tab_id=3DQ_Cn8JV4XYA" rel=3D"nofo=
llow">Link to e-mail address verification</a></p><p>This link will expire w=
ithin 5 minutes.</p><p>If you didn&#39;t create this account, just ignore t=
his message.</p>
</body>
</html>

------=_Part_2_1488711957.1660016366185--
```

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr: Add any non US-ASCII character to your templates and it will be encoded as `quoted-printable`.

On some [cached page](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:ztZ6L3QIgBsJ:https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeUtility.html&cd=4&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=nl) I found some old documentation which seem to explain the logic:

[image: screenshot of documentation]

> getEncoding
>
> public static String getEncoding(DataSource ds)
>
> Get the Content-Transfer-Encoding that should be applied to the input stream of this DataSource, to make it mail-safe.
>
> The algorithm used here is:
>
> - If the DataSource implements EncodingAware, ask it what encoding to use. If it returns non-null, return that value.
> - If the primary type of this datasource is "text" and if all the bytes in its input stream are US-ASCII, then the encoding is "7bit". If more than half of the bytes are non-US-ASCII, then the encoding is "base64". If less than half of the bytes are non-US-ASCII, then the encoding is "quoted-printable".
> - If the primary type of this datasource is not "text", then if all the bytes of its input stream are US-ASCII, the encoding is "7bit". If there is even one non-US-ASCII character, the encoding is "base64".
>
> **Parameters:**
> ds - the DataSource
>
> **Returns:**
> the encoding. This is either "7bit", "quoted-printable" or "base64"